# How to enumerate nested groups across domains?

Tags: winapi, vb6, active-directory, ldap, adsi

I am using MemberOf Attribute to enumerate nested groups. I have 2 domains, 2 groups and one user. Please see below for configuration:

- Domain DOMAIN-A has domain **global** group GROUP-A and USER-A.
- Domain DOMAIN-B has domain **local** group  GROUP-B.
- USER-A is member of GROUP-A.
- GROUP-A is member of GROUP-B.

Ideally, GROUP-A should contain GROUP-B in MemberOf Attribute but it does not even have a MemberOf attribute. (I am using an Softerra LDAP Browser 2.6)

Will it be populated after replication? If yes, how to change replication interval? I want to have instant replication.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a special attribute called tokenGroups. If you're on FX3.5 you can use this sample - http://dunnry.com/blog/2007/08/01/GettingActiveDirectoryGroupMembershipInNET35.aspx.

If you're wanting to use an older version of .Net or have some control over the process, you can parse out the attribute manually with something like this - http://dunnry.com/blog/EnumeratingTokenGroupsTokenGroupsInNET.aspx.

Finally, your service account or whatever context you're connecting to AD with will need to be in the Windows Authorization Access group if you use tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But tokenGroups is not giving me cross domain group for a user.

Comment: Just rerading your note and what you're trying to do isn't really possible without switching to universal groups.

Comment: Thanks. I have taught following solution. I shall be grateful if you can kindly provide your feedback.

Comment: Can you please review this algorithm?
http://mysticpaste.com/view/9591

Thanks,

Picaro

Comment: I am also adding it as a separate question just to give reviewer credit for his/her work. It is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909228/algo-to-enumerate-nested-groups-across-domains